# Android dialog layout squeeze when softkeyboard opened

Tags: android, layout, dialog

I have activity from which I open a dialog, the dialog class extends Dialog.
using dialog.show.

Now - when soft keyboard inflated all layout squeeze, instead of the keyboard being opened ontop the dialog.

In the layout of the dialog I have 3 scroll views inside a linear layout (only 1 of them is visible).

I tried to use:
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

but it does not work.

Yoav

Answer (score 3):

Check out this attribute that you can use in your manifest.  You might want to use adjustPan for that activity:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Comment: Did not help.... I have the attribute on the activity but it does not affect the dialog being opened from the activity. For the activity it works fine.... (sorry for the late reply)

Comment: Did not help me either.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I tried each one: 
1 - **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"** -> on activity tag on Manifest (or adjustNothing) or this same attribute in the root tag on dialog's layout xml file
2- **dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN); (or SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING)**
3- on dialog's layout xml file, set android:windowFullscreen="true".
For many cases each of them were solved. But for the dialog scenario, similar to your problem, my only solution that worked was:

```
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int heightPx = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    int widthPx = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(widthPx, heightPx);
```

with the **adjustPan** set on manifest for the given activity and dialog's layout file.